# Quarkus SQS consumer

Tags: amazon-sqs, quarkus

I am checking [this guide](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-sqs.html) on using Quarkus to consume from SQS.

The thing is I want to do it on an endless loop, fetching new messages every 10 seconds for example, and inserting some data from the message in a database using Hibernate Reactive.

I created a Quarkus Scheduler, but since it does not support returning a Uni, I had to block the response from Hibernate reactive, and got this error

```
2022-02-16 15:01:24,058 ERROR [de.sup.tea.con.SqsConsumer] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-9) Finished with error!: io.smallrye.mutiny.CompositeException: Multiple exceptions caught:
    [Exception 0] io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout
    [Exception 1] java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000061: Session is currently connecting to database
```

How is the best way to achieve what I need using Quarkus and reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Quarkus Scheduler is not in the I/O thread, it's not possible to use hibernate reactive. So, to make it work, you can work together with the EventBus. Below is a fully functional example. Code inside processReceivedMessageResponse method runs in the I/O thread and can depend on Hibernate Reactive.

```
import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.eventbus.EventBus
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty
import org.jboss.logging.Logger
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsAsyncClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.Message
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageResponse
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance

@ApplicationScoped
class SqsConsumer(
    private val eventBus: EventBus,
    private val logger: Logger,
    @ConfigProperty(name = "sqs.consumer.maxFetchedMessages")
    private val maxFetchedEvents: Int,
    private val handlers: Instance<MessageHandler>,
    private val sqsClient: SqsAsyncClient,
) {

    @Scheduled(every = "{sqs.consumer.interval}")
    fun execute() {
        handlers.stream().forEach { handler ->
            val handlerName = handler.javaClass.name
            logger.info("Fetching messages for $handlerName...")
            Uni
                .createFrom()
                .completionStage(fetchMessages(handler.queueUrl()))
                .subscribe()
                .with(
                    { response ->
                        val newEventsCount = response.messages().size
                        if (newEventsCount > 0) {
                            logger.info("$newEventsCount message(s) fetched for $handlerName.")
                            eventBus.send("receive-message-responses", ResponseHolder(handler, response))
                        } else {
                            logger.info("Queue was empty. Maybe next time.")
                        }
                    },
                    { logger.error("Error fetching messages!", it) }
                )
        }
    }

    @ConsumeEvent("receive-message-responses")
    fun processReceivedMessageResponse(holder: ResponseHolder): Uni<Void> {
        val handler = holder.handler
        val handlerName = handler.javaClass.name
        val messageResponse = holder.receiveMessageResponse
        logger.info("Processing messages for $handlerName...")
        return Uni
            .createFrom()
            .item(holder)
            .flatMap { handler.process(messageResponse.messages().map { message -> message.body() }) }
            .onItem()
            .invoke { _ ->
                logger.info("Processing succeeded. Deleting processed events from the queue...")
                messageResponse
                    .messages()
                    .forEach { eventBus.send("processed-messages", MessageHolder(handler, it)) }
            }
            .replaceWithVoid()
            .onFailure()
            .invoke { it -> logger.error("Error processing messages!", it) }
    }

    @ConsumeEvent("processed-messages")
    fun deleteProcessedMessages(holder: MessageHolder): Uni<Void> {
        val handler = holder.handler
        val message = holder.message
        return Uni
            .createFrom()
            .completionStage(
                sqsClient.deleteMessage {
                    it
                        .queueUrl(handler.queueUrl())
                        .receiptHandle(message.receiptHandle())
                }
            )
            .onItem()
            .invoke { _ -> logger.info("Message ${message.messageId()} deleted from the queue!") }
            .onFailure()
            .invoke { it -> logger.error("Could not delete message ${message.messageId()} from the queue!", it) }
            .replaceWithVoid()
    }

    private fun fetchMessages(queueUrl: String): CompletionStage<ReceiveMessageResponse> {
        return sqsClient
            .receiveMessage {
                it
                    .maxNumberOfMessages(maxFetchedEvents)
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
            }
    }
}

class ResponseHolder(
    val handler: MessageHandler,
    val receiveMessageResponse: ReceiveMessageResponse,
)

class MessageHolder(
    val handler: MessageHandler,
    val message: Message,
)
```

Comment: Many thanks to Clement Escoffier btw, who guided me through the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code would help to understand what you are doing. Based on information you have in your question I would suggest you you create the Uni with code like this:

```
Uni.createFrom().item(returnDataFromDb());
```